# How do I extract a table from a pdf file using pymupdf

Tags: python, pdf

My work demands I use `pymupdf` to extract tables from pdf files and export to csv format.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How uniform are the .pdfs? Do any of them contain scanned content that needs to be OCRed? How far along the process are you? Do you know if the tables are uniform? Are they well formed tables?

Comment: Why don't you try using Camelot library for this task?

Answer (score 3):

I looked into this and was amazed by how powerful pymupdf is to extract tables.
In the pdf format I was looking at, I was able to extract the table outlines using pymupdfs .get_drawings() attribute. A little messing around with the coordinates of those enabled me to extract the grid layout of the table, which can then be used together with the text extraction. Please note the SVG preview only works in jupyter lab or notebook as far as I know.

My code below:

```
import fitz
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class PDF():
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.pdf_doc = fitz.open(file)
    @staticmethod
    def rect_to_svg_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill, stroke):
        width = x2 - x1
        height = y2 - y1

        svg_rect = f'<rect x="{x1}" y="{y1}" width="{width}" height="{height}" fill="{fill}" stroke="{stroke}" />\n'
        return svg_rect
    @staticmethod
    def merge_bins(arr):
        result = []
        n = len(arr)
        i = 0
        while i < n:
            if i + 1 < n and arr[i + 1] - arr[i] < 4:
                result.append((arr[i + 1] + arr[i]) / 2)
                i += 2
            else:
                result.append(arr[i])
                i += 1
        result = np.array(result)
        return result
    def get_layout(self, page, skip_rects=0, fill="white", stroke="black"):
        pdf_page = self.pdf_doc[int(page)]
        mediabox = pdf_page.mediabox
        width = mediabox.x1 - mediabox.x0
        height = mediabox.y1 - mediabox.y0
        svg_lines = ''
        for rect in pdf_page.get_drawings()[skip_rects:]:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = rect['rect'][0], rect['rect'][1], rect['rect'][2], rect['rect'][3]
            svg_lines += self.rect_to_svg_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill, stroke)
        svg_content = f'<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="{width}" height="{height}" viewBox="0 0 {width} {height}">\n' \
          f'<rect x="0" y="0" width="{width}" height="{height}" fill="white" />\n' \
          f'{svg_lines}' \
          f'</svg>'
        return svg_content

    def multipage_table(self, pages, headers, skip_rows=0, skip_cols=0, skip_rects=0):
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        r_ind=-1
        for p in pages:
            pdf_page = self.pdf_doc[int(p)]

            x1_values = []
            y1_values = []
            for rect in pdf_page.get_drawings()[skip_rects:]:
                x1_values.append(rect['rect'][0])
                y1_values.append(rect['rect'][1])
            x_bins = np.sort(list(set(x1_values)))
            y_bins = np.sort(list(set(y1_values)))
            y_grid = self.merge_bins(y_bins)
            x_grid = self.merge_bins(x_bins)

            for row in range(skip_rows, len(y_grid)-1):
                r_ind+=1
                y1, y2 = y_grid[row],y_grid[row+1]

                for col in range(skip_cols, len(x_grid)-1):
                    x1, x2 = x_grid[col],x_grid[col+1]
                    cell_text = pdf_page.get_text("text", clip=(x1, y1, x2, y2))  # Extract text within cell boundaries
                    df.loc[r_ind,headers[col]] = cell_text.replace("\n","")
        return df
```

This is then used like this:

```
from IPython.display import SVG

page_number = 39
columns=[
    "<1>", "<2>", "<3>", 
    "<4>", "<5>", "<6>", 
    "<7>", "<8>", "<9>",
    "<10>", "<11>",
    "<12>",
    "<13>", "<14>",
    "<15>"
]
file = "PDF_FILE.PDF"
pdf_file = PDF(file)
svg_content = pdf_file.get_layout(page_number,skip_rects=1)
SVG(svg_content)

# If the format is good you can proceed to extract tables
# pages = np.linspace(39,56,18)
# df = pdf_file.multipage_table(pages, headers=columns, skip_rows=4, skip_cols=0, skip_rects=1)
# df.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

Please note this works for the specific layout I was working with. You obviously need to make adjustments to make it work with your format.

Comment: Thx, this work for me. You save my day.

Answer (score 3):

As of PyMuPDF (1.23), it supports table extraction. The following simple example prints the contents of the first table on each page of the document.

```
import fitz

doc = fitz.open('data/doc.pdf')
for page in doc:
    tabs = page.find_tables()
    if tabs.tables:
        print(tabs[0].extract())
```

You can export the table content as a Pandas data frame as well.
Check PyMuPDF documentation on the matter [here](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes-text.html#how-to-extract-table-content-from-documents)

Comment: Works great! Thanks! I couldn't find a direct "table to dataframe" method, but this worked: df = pd.DataFrame(tabs[0].extract())

Answer (score 2):

You are out of luck, I'm afraid. The PDF format has no internal representation of a table structure, which makes it difficult to extract tables for analysis. You have to infer the existence of a table by seeing where the columns of data have been lined up.

There are modules that will do this for you: one is [Excalibur](https://pypi.org/project/excalibur-py/). But `pymupdf` is about extracting text as text and that will leave you having to do the parsing and inferencing yourself. That is a fairly ambitious project.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version (1.23) of PyMuPDF / Fitz has the support for finding tables.

https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.find_tables. I was using PDF Plumber earlier and was running issues but so far I am happy with PyMuPDF as an alternative for PDFPlumber in extracting table information.

Answer (score 0):

Excalibur is the GUI version of camelot

**Installation**
https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install.html

**Tutorial**
https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/

This should do the job for you. There is direct export to csv. The default ouput is a dataframe which can be exported to excel or csv

Answer (score 0):

I needed to work with pymupdf so I made a custom solution.

If it works for at least one person, I would be happy.

Please remember I did it for a specific problematic and the code may break for you.

I did it in an open way so you will be able to upgrade this code to your specific purpose.

If you make a better generalize solution, I would gladly use it, don't hesitate to post it ! (this one took me 3 hours...)

```
import fitz  # this is pymupd, pip3 install PyMuPDF

# WARNING, this is a bad code, please use it knowing it may break easely
# Author: nah, I'm joking, nobody wants to own this shit XD


def get_page_bloc_tuple_2list(pdf_path):
    doc = fitz.open(pdf_path)
    page_bloc_tuple_2list = [page.get_text_words() for page in doc]  # for local (up to date)
    # page_bloc_tuple_2list = [page.getTextWords() for page in doc]  # for lambda (outdated)
    return page_bloc_tuple_2list


def get_line_dict_list(pdf_path):
    line_dict_list = []
    for page_block_list in get_page_bloc_tuple_2list(pdf_path):
        if len(page_block_list) == 0: continue
        word_dict_list = []
        y0_temp = page_block_list[0][1]
        y1_temp = page_block_list[0][3]
        for bloc in page_block_list:
            x0, y0, x1, y1, word, _, _, _ = bloc
            if y0 != y0_temp:
                line_dict = {
                    "y": (y0_temp, y1_temp),
                    "word_dict_list": word_dict_list
                }
                line_dict_list.append(line_dict)
                word_dict_list = []
                y0_temp = y0
                y1_temp = y1
            word_dict = {
                "word": word,
                "x": (x0, x1)
            }
            word_dict_list.append(word_dict)
    return line_dict_list


def get_word_list(line_dict):
    return [word_dict['word'] for word_dict in line_dict['word_dict_list']]


def is_title_line(line_dict, title_word_list):
    line_word_list = get_word_list(line_dict)
    for w in title_word_list:
        for sub_word in w.split(): # we need to comaprate substring
            if sub_word not in line_word_list:
                return False
    return True

def get_title_line(line_dict_list, title_word_list):
    for line_dict in line_dict_list:
        if is_title_line(line_dict, title_word_list):
            return line_dict
        

def get_word(title_x, line_dict):
    title_x0, title_x1 = title_x
    for word_dict in line_dict['word_dict_list']:
        word = word_dict['word']
        x0 = word_dict['x'][0]
        if title_x0 <= x0 and x0 <= title_x1:
           return word


def get_row_list(pdf_path, title_word_list):
    line_dict_list = get_line_dict_list(pdf_path)
    title_line = get_title_line(line_dict_list, title_word_list)
    row_list = [get_word_list(title_line)]
    title_index = line_dict_list.index(title_line)
    for idx, line_dict in enumerate(line_dict_list):
        if idx <= title_index: continue
        row = []
        for title_word_dict in title_line['word_dict_list']:
            row.append(get_word(title_word_dict['x'], line_dict))
        row_list.append(row)
    return row_list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pdf_path = "my_filename.pdf"
    title_word_list = ["name", "surname", "whatever"]
    get_row_list(pdf_path, title_word_list)
```